# Refresh only once when intent to new activity

Tags: android

In android studio, I can refresh the activity using the following method. When Button onClick, it refreshData at current activity.

```
public void refreshData(){

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

Now the thing I want to do is, when Button onclick, it jump from Activity A.class to B.class, and instantly refresh B.class. I needed it because of pulling database data at first time .

In order words I need refresh second activity when any activity jump to it.

Second activity:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);


        getData();   //get database data


        addData();   //set data to variable
        refreshData();  // I wish to refresh the Activity 2 Interface
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call your database entries from **Activity B's** `onCreate()` method, so that every time Activity B is loaded (called from any Activity), the database entries are re-fetched and filled into the UI. Pretty straight forward, isn't it?

Comment: please kindly view the new edit on this question... second activity code is attach ... I face a problem that refreshData() become infinite loop ... Always refresh

Comment: Add the methods too. What does refreshData contain?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom method for pulling  database data in second activity . 
then  call the custom method in  oncreate of second activity .

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
         getdataMethod();// pulling  database data
}
```

Comment: please kindly view the new edit on this question... second activity code is attach ... I face a problem that refreshData() become infinite loop ... Always refresh

Comment: remove  refreshData();  in onCreate